# Flux gitops not deploying despite source being added and showing my commit

Tags: flux, gitops

Just working on getting a flux setup up and running using this tutorial from Victor from the Devops Toolkit https://gist.github.com/vfarcic/0431989df4836eb82bdac0cc53c7f3d6

Managed to add the sources ok.  Not able to see anything being deployed into the staging namespace when i add the first setup (and then update the tag number).  I can see the source updates and references my commit id with the details into staging (from the flux-staging repo) but i do not see anything deployed.

Not sure if I am missing something in the kustomizations section?  Only seeing the flux-system in there.

```
flux get sources git
NAME            REVISION        SUSPENDED       READY   MESSAGE                                                                                                                        
devops-toolkit  master/2c2e5b5  False           True    stored artifact for revision 'master/2c2e5b54d5c341f43c9cc3f8ac31b470b47098fb'                                                 
flux-system     main/844cd02    False           True    stored artifact for revision 'main/844cd027630bc2d457aafcae14e753edb3e45ac6'                                                   
staging         master/b4ce767  False           True    stored artifact for revision 'master/b4ce7679d9487041d545c3b44548dbd820fdc587'                                                 

flux get kustomizations
NAME            REVISION        SUSPENDED       READY   MESSAGE
flux-system     main/844cd02    False           True    Applied revision: main/844cd02
```

Anyone any pointers on where might be going wrong?

Comment: Looks good, perhaps you should check the logs in source-controller and kustomization-controller